# Google Place Autocomplete Cannot Resolve Field in Place.Field in compatible library

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I'm trying to migrate to the new Place AutoComplete using this migration guide provided by Google. [Click Here for the Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration).

In that, I'm following the 'Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity', section, just before [Place Picker is Deprecated](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#place-picker-deprecation) Section.

When I used the

> implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

new client library, I did not face any problem and the place autocomplete worked just fine. But, **I had to move to the [Comparability Library](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compat) which uses**

> implementation
>   'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'

**because I have to use a place picker too**, and if I use the new client library

> implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

I could not use the Place Picker.

This is the code for the Place AutoComplete:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
      /**
         * Initialize Places. For simplicity, the API key is hard-coded. In a production
         * environment we recommend using a secure mechanism to manage API keys.
         */
        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY");
        }
    }


     public void startAutocompleteActivity() {
        // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

        // Start the autocomplete intent.
        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        /**
         * Override the activity's onActivityResult(), check the request code, and
         * do something with the returned place data (in this example it's place name and place ID).
         */
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
                } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                    Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // The user canceled the operation.
                }
            }
        }
```

So why are the following methods and variables undefined?

- Places.isInitialized()
- Field in Place.Field
- Autocomplete and AutocompleteActivityMode in  Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
              AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
              .build(this);

Android Studio says **'Cannot Resolve Symbol'** for the above. And I have imported the correct library too: `import com.google.android.libraries.places.compat.Places;`

Comment: Finally, I just used `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'` for Place Autocomplete and used the same old `'com.google.android.gms:play-services'` dependency for Place Picker.